# Kate Editor Reset Settings

Tags: linux, editor, kate

How can I reset the changings, i have done in Kate on a non KDE desktop?

In Settings under Configure Kate in Fonts & Colors i mistakenly changed Vim(dark) to "Use KDE Colour Scheme" The Problem is, that it overwrote Vim.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Thank you. I will check on it! Found solution already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Kate developer here: There is no option for that in the user interface.

Resetting all configuration can be done by removing configuration files. What you are probably looking for are `kateschemarc` and `katesyntaxhighlightingrc` that are in your home folders: Probably in `~/.config5/` (Plasma 5), or `~/.kde/config` (KDE 4). If you delete (or move) these files, your highlighting information is reset to the default.

Update 2021-01-25: Kate (more precisely KTextEditor) versions released in 2021 have a redesigned theme support. Kate will ship with many themes by default, see https://kate-editor.org/themes/. In addition, the themes that are shipped by default cannot be changed. These have to be copied first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was under ~/.config/kateschemarc